# Verilog, truncate genvar width size

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

How do I truncate the width of a genvar variable? For instance, if I have:

```
parameter LENGTH = 8;

genvar i;
for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i = i + 2) begin
   somemodule #(WIDTH($clog2(LENGTH))
               )
               tmp (.a(i)
                   ,.b(i+1)
                   ,.c(output)
                   );
end
endgenerate
```

When I simulate in ModelSim, I would get port size does not match connection size. I know the problem lies in that genvar is 32 bit wide, and my module's width varies.

I tried

```
genvar [$clog2(LENGTH)-1:0] i;
```

and

```
.a(i[$clog2(LENGTH)-1:0])
```

but they are not syntactically correct.

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an intermediate parameter declared with a data type for this

```
parameter int LENGTH = 8;
parameter int WIDTH  = $clog2(LENGTH);
for(genvar i = 0; i < LENGTH; i = i + 2) begin

   parameter bit [WIDTH-1:0] A = i;
   somemodule #(.WIDTH(WIDTH))
               )
               tmp (.a(A)
                   ,.b(A+1'b1)
                   ,.c(output)
                   );
end
```